# C++ convert to assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

this is my assignment.
I've done my code for this assembly, but is there any way to make the convert speed more fast?
thank in advance for any helps ;D

```
//Convert this nested for loop to assembly instructions
    for (a = 0; a < y; a++)
        for (b = 0; b < y; b++)
            for (c = 0; c < y; c++)
                if ((a + 2 * b - 8 * c) == y)
                    count++;

convert
    _asm {
                mov ecx,0
                mov ax, 0
                mov bx, 0
                mov cx, 0

                Back:
                push cx
                push bx
                push ax
                add bx, bx
                mov dx, 8
                mul dx
                add cx, bx
                sub cx, ax
                pop ax
                pop bx
                cmp cx, y
                jne increase
                inc count
                increase : pop cx
                          inc ax
                           cmp ax, y
                           jl Back

                           inc bx
                           mov ax, 0
                           cmp bx, y
                           jl Back

                           inc cx
                           mov ax, 0
                           mov bx, 0
                           cmp cx, y
                           jl Back

        }
```

Comment: The fastest you could go would be to work out the analytical solution for the number of intersections of that linear function with the plane `f(a,b,c) = y`. Barring that, though, the usual techniques would be thinks like loop unrolling and subsequent vectorization.

Comment: Maybe, it's me, but "number of intersections of that linear function with the plane f(a,b,c) = y" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Take a look at the output of a good optimizing compiler, you might be surprised.

Answer (score 4):

Some generic tricks:

1. Make your loop counters count down instead of up. You eliminate a compare that way.
2. Learn the magic of `LEA` to compute expressions that include addition and scaling by certain powers of 2. You won't need a `MUL` in there anywhere.
3. Hoist loop-invariant work outside the inner loop. `a + 2*b` is constant for every iteration of the c loop.
4. Use `SI`, `DI` to hold values.  That should help you avoid all those `push` and `pop` instructions.
5. If your values fit in 8 bits, use `AH`, `AL`, etc. to make more effective use of your registers.

Oh, and you don't need that `mov ax, 0` after `inc cx`, because `AX` is already 0 there.

Specific to this algorithm:  If `y` is odd, skip iterations where `a` is even, and vice versa.  Nearly 2x speedup awaits...  (Work out with pencil and paper if you wonder why.)  Hint:  You don't need to test every iteration, either.  You can simply step by 2s, if you're clever enough.

Or better still, work out a closed form that allows you to calculate the answer directly. ;-)

Comment: Closed form solution is not hard. First solve for a. Then solve for b given c=0. Then adjust for c != 0. Even if you don't go for the closed form solution, you can knock off an exponent by changing the order of iteration to c, b, a, then solving for a. Algorithmic improvements trump assembly language.

Comment: @RaymondChen : Oh, I agree wholeheartedly.  I suspect the pedagogical purpose here was to learn the assembly more than to optimize it into irrelevance, though.

Comment: I agree with some and disagree with others :p  First, closed form solution isn't as trivial as you make it sound.  Why?  You can't just solve for a, solve for b.... It's easy to hand wave, though. I'll let you answer that yourself when you try to do it.  The closed form formula is somewhat quadratic.  How can you solve for a, b, or c in that expression ((a + 2 * b - 8 * c) == y) to get a quadratic expression?  To demonstrate assembly language optimization, I would have given something that is already optimized by algorithm optimization.  Then again, I am not the instructor.

Comment: @thang:  I'll admit that Raymond Chen probably has a leg up on most of us here in the algorithm department.

Comment: You want to know how many {b, c} combinations satisfy 0 <= 2b - 8c < y. For c=0, the answer is y/2. For c=1, the answer is min(y, (y+8)/2) = min(y, y/2 + 4), and so on up to c=y-1. This is basically y^2/2 minus a triangle term to handle the min.

Comment: thanks for everyone comment .Yet, i am still very basic learner , i am quite confuse by reading all of senior (you ) suggestion, which i dont really understand :(

Comment: @user3040078:  If you go to my list above, try working on a couple of those.  For example, the first one (make loops count down) is a really basic and common transformation.  Still, Raymond Chen's initial point is one most worth learning:  Algorithmic improvements trump assembly language.  It's also 100% portable, and never goes out of date!

Comment: @RaymondChen, y=10, count=11 (y^2/2 = 50).  y=50, count=241 (y^2/2 = 1250).  y=100, count=950.  y=500, count=23500.  Not y^2/2 minus a "triangle term" (whatever triangle term means).  "how many {b, c} combinations satisfy 0 <= 2b - 8c < y" is not quite complete.  You want to know how many (b,c) where b,c are both positive integers >=0 and <y s.t. y >= 2b - 8c > 0.  Bounding conditions can create pieces that make it difficult to tally.  The details prevent a simple quadratic formula, and that's my point.  If it were so simple, you would have just posted the formula.  Hand waving is easy :p

Comment: The triangle term is the difference between y and y/2 + 8c. This is an arithmetic series, geometrically a triangle. And yes the constraint implied is that b and c are in [0, y). You just need the formula for how many b satisfy the condition given c (the "min") and then sum over c.

Comment: Still no formula... :p

Answer (score 3):

When you are optimizing, always start high and go low, i.e. start at the algorithm level, and when everything is exhausted, go to the assembly conversion.

First, observe that:

```
8 * c = (a + 2 * b - y)
```

Has a unique c solution for each triplet (a,b,y).

What does this mean?  Your 3 loops can be collapsed into 2.  This is a huge reduction from a runtime with theta y^3 to theta y^2.

Rewrite the code:

```
for (a = 0; a < y; a++)
    for (b = 0; b < y; b++) {
        c = (a+2*b-y);
        if (((c%8)==0) && (c >= 0)) count++;
    }
```

Next observe that c>=0 means:

```
      a+2*b-y >= 0 
      a+2*b >= y
      a >= y-2b
```

Note that the two loops can be interchanged, which gives:

```
for (b = 0; b < y; b++) {
for (a = max(y-2*b,0); a < y; a++) {
        if (((a+2*b-y)%8)==0) count++;
} }
```

Which we can split into two:

```
for (b = 0; b < y/2; b++) {
for (a = y-2*b; a < y; a++) {
        if (((a+2*b-y)%8)==0) count++;
} }

for (b = y/2; b < y; b++) {
for (a = 0; a < y; a++) {
        if (((a+2*b-y)%8)==0) count++;
} }
```

Now we have entirely eliminated c.  We can't eliminate a or b altogether without coming up with a closed form formula (or at least partial closed form formula), why?

So here are several exercises that will get you "there".

1. how can we get rid of %8?  can we eliminate a or b now?
2. observe that for each y, there is approximately theta y^2 counts.  why is it that there is no single closed form quadratic (i.e. a*y^2+b*y+c) that give us the correct count?
3. given 2, how would one go about coming up with a closed form formula?

And now conversion to assembly language will give you a small improvement in the grand scheme of things :p

(I hope all the details are right.  Please correct if you see a mistake)

Answer (score 0):

In [Assembly Language Step-by-Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470497025) Jeff writes on page 230,

*Now, speed optimization is a very slippery business in the x86 world, Having instructions in the CPU cache versus having to pull them from memory is a speed difference that swamps most speed differences among the instructions themselves. Other factors come into play in the most recent Pentium-class CPUs that make generalizations about instruction speed almost impossible, and certainly impossible to state with any precision.*

Assuming you're on an x86 machine, my advice would be soak up all that Math in the other answers the best you can for optimizations.